# can asp.net Timer Event make server busy?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am coding a Social network for my university that maximum user of this website will be 2000 person ( i guess ) and , maximum online User about 200 person !
for commenting system of this Social Network I used An Update Panel and A Timer with `TimeInterval= 1 Min` it means after one min the `GridView` that shows the Posts and Comments will be `Bind` again

```
  protected void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    post.DataSource = GetData("select something");
    post.DataBind();
}
```

now my question is can this function make my server so busy and slow ?

Comment: This depends on how big is your web server and how heavy is the query. I find it **extremely difficult** to estimate if this setup will overload your server. I would suggest taking a look into the `SignalR` library that offers real-time functionality.

Comment: SignalR is a good package but i didnt find any good doc to help me in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though a partial postback is not as heavy as a full postback, it still requires a lot of "bogness" that is unnecessary.

A better solution is to use [SignalR](http://signalr.net/). SignalR adds real-time web functionality to your site. What this means is that instead of your ASP.NET application checking every minute if there are new comments, SignalR notifies you when there are new comments. So if a new comment is posted, SignalR sends a message to your application. Then your application refreshes the comments section. Its a lot more efficient that polling every minute!

There are some [demos here](http://philknows.net/SignalR) that you can try out see it working in live action.

Comment: thank , i read about signalR , but i dont know how use this package! there are several docs but i didnt find any good example for **SignalR sends a message to your application** ! any idea ? or any good example?

Comment: @MohammadOlfatMiri - There is a good [tutorial here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20) that steps you through creating a new SignalR application from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

No, it will **not** make your server busy.. , **1 min Timer interval** will be good.

Server will be busy if you will implement more **then 2,3 ajax controls** in a page. and with no time management.

thanks